# When i click on radio button then its true or automatically other Span value goes to false

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I clicked on the radio button, the `span` text changes to `true` or other should be `false`.

[image: Screenshot]

This code works perfectly fine:

```js
$('table').on('change', ':radio', function() {
 $(this).next('span').text('True').closest('td')
       .siblings().find('span').text('False');
});
```

```html
<tr>
  <td><input type="radio" name="attandance"><span>True</span></td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="attandance"><span>True</span></td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="attandance"><span>True</span></td>
</tr>
```

When I click on the radio button, it changes to "True" and when we click on the other radio button on the same row it remains the same.

I want to convert it back again, true to false.

Hope you all got my point.

Comment: Show your HTML. We can't tell if your javascript is reasonable without knowing what the DOM structure is like.

Comment: Thanks For reply please check again

Comment: Checkout my other solution with only CSS.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that radio button is always selected because change event is triggered on selected one not on all of them. So you need to set correct to True and the rest of the them to False, this is how I would do it:

```js
$('table').on('change', ':radio', function () {
    $(this).next('span').text('True').closest('td')
           .siblings().find('span').text('False');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
<td> <input  type='radio' name='attandance' ><span>False</span></td>
<td> <input  type='radio' name='attandance' ><span>False</span></td>
<td> <input  type='radio' name='attandance' ><span>False</span></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**EDIT**: And a bonus you can use this without JS:

```css
input[type="radio"]:not(:checked) + span::before {
    content: 'False';
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + span::before {
    content: "True";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
<td> <input  type='radio' name='attandance' ><span></span></td>
<td> <input  type='radio' name='attandance' ><span></span></td>
<td> <input  type='radio' name='attandance' ><span></span></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is perfectttt

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset the text of other span elements of the same table row as the radio button being clicked. Consider using the `closest()` method as shown below to achieve this:

```js
$('table').on('change', ':radio', function() {
  
  /* Access the closest tr ancestor to the radio button being clicked */
  var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
  
  /* Reset all span descendants for the anscestor tr to the default text of false */
  $('span', tr).text('false');

  /* Update the span relative to the checked radio button as you currently are */
  $(this).next('span').text('true');
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td> John </td>
    <td> <input type='radio' name='attandance0'><span>false</span></td>
    <td> <input type='radio' name='attandance0'><span>false</span></td>
    <td> <input type='radio' name='attandance0'><span>false</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Peter </td>
    <td> <input type='radio' name='attandance1'><span>false</span></td>
    <td> <input type='radio' name='attandance1'><span>false</span></td>
    <td> <input type='radio' name='attandance1'><span>false</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Andrew </td>
    <td> <input type='radio' name='attandance2'><span>false</span></td>
    <td> <input type='radio' name='attandance2'><span>false</span></td>
    <td> <input type='radio' name='attandance1'><span>false</span></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You don't need to use `this.checked` (use `"True"`) it will be confusing, since it's always true, since you can't uncheck radio button.

Comment: @jcubic yes that's correct - have just updated answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

you just need to reset each radio button on change...

```js
 $('table').on('change', ':radio', function () {
        $(this).parents('table').find('span').text('false');
  if($(this). prop("checked") == true){
         $(this).next('span').text('true')
        }            
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
  <td> <input  type='radio' name='attandance' value="ch" /><span>false </span></td>
  <td> <input  type='radio' name='attandance' /><span>false </span></td>
  <td> <input  type='radio' name='attandance' /><span> false</span></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```